# Correct usage of /srv on debian systems

Tags: linux, debian, filesystems, fhs

I'm a bit confused about what goes inside `/srv` and looking for good practices about its usage on Debian.

[Acording to the FHS](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html#SRVDATAFORSERVICESPROVIDEDBYSYSTEM): "`/srv` contains site-specific data which is served by this system".

However I'm not sure if things like MySQL data files, munin's rrd files and stuff like that can/should be stored in `/srv` since they are not "served" directly.

I'm not asking if it's possible or how can it be accomplished, I'm asking about your experiences and good practices.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I personally use the `/srv` hierarchy to serve:

- web server static content under `/srv/www`. In Debian (and RHEL derivatives) where SELinux compliance is important, this path is listed as `httpd_sys_content` by default:

  ```
  /srv/([^/]*/)?www(/.*)? all files  system_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0
  ```
- NFSv4 exports. These filesystems are mounted under `var/exports` and bind-mounted under `/srv/nfsv4/$export`, and `/srv/nfsv4` is configured to be the `fsid=0`. This path is also considered in the default SELinux policy:

  ```
  /srv/([^/]*/)?nfsv4(/.*)? all files  system_u:object_r:nfs_t:s0
  ```
- in Debian systems (i.e., no `cobbler`) I used to host all my `tftp` structure for provisioning, under `/srv/tftpd/`.

Another usual practice is to dedicate a logical volume to each of these services, this way you can specify `mount` options to help hardening your system, e.g., by mounting `/srv/tftpd` with `ro,nodev,nosuid,noexec`.

Comment: Thanks for your comments and recomendations, they are very useful. What about other data like mysql databases or git repositories? Do you consider it srv material?

Comment: WRT `git`, that's a very personal choice, and depends on whether you use `gitblit`, `gitolite` or any other management tool. I have used `/srv/git` to host repos using plain `git` and `git-shell` + pubkey auth in the past and still do in boxes with low resources or not very demanding environments. WRT MySQL, I don't think it fits this definition of "site-specific data to be served", as it is not _served_, but rather used through the MySQL engine process.

Comment: Did you mean `/var/exports`? Also, what happens if you want to share something that's not mounted under it, e.g. `/mnt/cdrom` or `/media/cdrom`?

Comment: I usually use `/var/exports` to mount dedicated LVs for NFSv4. I bind mount them on `/srv/nfsv4`, though. It is not a common requirement in enterprise environments to share a CDROM.

Comment: @dawud, why not mount them directly under `/srv/nfs4`?